# Get position of the set bit in C

Tags: c

I have a 4 byte data.Each bit will be acting as a switch.I need to enable/disable the switch based on the bits value in the 4 byte data.What will be the optimized way to get the positions of bit that are set out of 32 bits..?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.
1) Right shift and check all the bits and make the decision accordingly T.C for this would be O(32).
2) If  a decision is to be taken such that fixed positions should be set then , You can create a mask and then perform binary and operation '&' and take the decision. Again T.C in O(32).

I can think of few more similar approaches.